# How to make a device disappear from device manager on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, device-manager

I have a laptop which comes with onboard bluetooth chip. I recently added a wireless card to my laptop which has a bluetooth chip inside. So now I got 2 bluetooth devices in my device manager which has caused me some problems. I tried and uninstalled the first bluetooth device, but each time I restart windows installs the driver by itself. I also tried and disabled the first bluetooth device but still have issues using the second one which is faster and 4th version of bt. I need to delete the first bluetooth from device manager, I mean make it disappear. Since it is onboard chip I can't phisically remove the hardware. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: How do you know the issues are caused by the first device if it is disabled?

Comment: There exists a tool to block driver updates on Windows Update you will have to use that

Comment: The issues are caused by the first device since when I enable it back in the device manager the issues are gone.

Answer (score 1):

In your laptop's BIOS, you should be able to disable onboard devices, such as Bluetooth, WiFi, etc. Check your computer/motherboard"s manual on how to access BIOS on boot. Typically, you will see something along the lines of press the F2 key, F12 key flash during boot up.

Comment: Unfortunately not possible!

It is sony vpcsb18gg and there is only an option to disable all wireless devices together in the bios.